Windows self-elevating batch scripts (no third-party / external tools)
I want to create self-elevating batch scripts in windows without having to use yet another third-party / external tool.
(The solution must also work when installing / downloading external tools is not allowed.)

This solution is based only on cmd.exe and Windows' built-in shortcut (.lnk) feature (for the elevated prompt).
Files
cmda.lnk (see also: How to open an elevated cmd using command line for Windows?)

target = %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe
shortcut properties / Advanced... (button) / Run as administrator = ON

sudo.bat
@start cmda.lnk /c "cd /d %cd% && %*"

lib-admin.cmd
:: usage (from another batch):
::
:: v1
:: @call lib-admin.cmd :runAsAdmin %0 %* && (call :run %*)
:: @goto :eof
::
:: v2
:: @call lib-admin.cmd :isAdmin
:: @if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (call sudo %0 %*) else (call :run %*)
:: @goto :eof
::
:: v3 (fallthrough)
:: @call lib-admin.cmd :isAdmin
:: @if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (@call sudo %0 %* & @goto :eof)

@call %*
@goto :eof

:: return 0=admin, 1=not admin
:isAdmin
@fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% > nul
@echo DEBUG lib-admin.cmd %0 isAdmin=%errorlevel% (0 = admin, 1 = not admin)
@goto :eof

:: TODO
:runAsAdmin
@echo DEBUG lib-admin.cmd %0 %*
@call :isAdmin
@if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (echo DEBUG lib-admin.cmd %0 sudo %1 %2... && call sudo %*)
@rem @echo DEBUG lib-admin.cmd %0 exit
@goto :eof

Tests
lib-admin-test-v1.bat (note: I prefer this solution)
@call lib-admin.cmd :runAsAdmin %0 %* && (call :run %*)
@pause
@goto :eof

:run
@echo admin code
@goto :eof

lib-admin-test-v2.bat
@call lib-admin.cmd :isAdmin
@if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (call sudo %0 %*) else (call :run %*)
@pause
@goto :eof

:run
@echo admin code
@goto :eof

lib-admin-test-v3.bat
@call lib-admin.cmd :isAdmin
@if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (@call sudo %0 %* & (@pause && @goto :eof))

:run
@echo admin code
@pause

